# makefile: compile files with the output in other directory

Tags: makefile

I try to compile many files and put the output in other directory. I have this Makefile

```
CC = gcc
BINDIR = bin
SRCDIR = src

SRCS = $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name *.c)
BINS = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%, $(BINDIR)/%, $(SRCS:.c=.exe))

all: $(BINS)

$(BINS): $(SRCS)
        @mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
        $(CC) -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -rf bin
```

and this directory structure

```
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── bye.c
    └── hello.c
```

when I use make, I get this

```
$ make
gcc -o bin/bye.exe src/bye.c
gcc -o bin/hello.exe src/bye.c
```

why the both times use `src/bye.c` as source file?

#### EDIT

and how I can compile any file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your rule uses `$<`. As explained in https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html:

> `$<`
>
> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule (see [Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules)).

And `src/bye.c` is the first element of `$(SRCS)`.

Comment: Probably by using a [pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html): `bin/%.exe: src/%.c; $(CC) -o $@ $<`